Using a Markov Chain to Define a Thunderstorm
I was curious and wanted to see if the behavior of Thunderstorms can be defined using a set of Markov Chains:

Thunderstorms persist for some time but are less common than periods without thunderstorms.
Lightning can only occur during thunderstorms.
When lightning strikes, it's more likely to be followed by more lightning
As time passes without lightning, the probability of lightning decreases

To do this, I think we need to define 2 stochastic processes for both thunderstorm and lightening.
Part 1: I think the Thunderstorm part is straightforward:
$$
X_t = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if no thunderstorm on day } t \\
1 & \text{if thunderstorm on day } t
\end{cases}
$$
$$
\begin{align}
P(X_{t+1} = 0 | X_t = 0) &= p_{00} \\
P(X_{t+1} = 1 | X_t = 0) &= p_{01} = 1 - p_{00} \\
P(X_{t+1} = 0 | X_t = 1) &= p_{10} \\
P(X_{t+1} = 1 | X_t = 1) &= p_{11} = 1 - p_{10}
\end{align}
$$
Filling some basic numbers:
$$
P = \begin{bmatrix}
0.9 & 0.1 \\
0.4 & 0.6
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Part 2: The lightening part was more difficult:
$$
Y_t = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if no lightning strike in hour } t \\
1 & \text{if lightning strike in hour } t
\end{cases}
$$
For $Y_t$, I think we need a time-dependent transition probability that's conditional on $X_t = 1$ (i.e., during a thunderstorm). Let $\tau_t$ be the time since the last lightning strike. Then:
$$
P(Y_{t+1} = 1 | Y_t = 1, X_t = 1) = q_{11}(\tau_t) = \min(0.8, 0.5 + 0.3e^{-0.1\tau_t})
$$
$$
P(Y_{t+1} = 1 | Y_t = 0, X_t = 1) = q_{01}(\tau_t) = \max(0.1, 0.5 - 0.4e^{-0.05\tau_t})
$$
$$
P(Y_{t+1} = 0 | Y_t = 1, X_t = 1) = 1 - q_{11}(\tau_t)
$$
$$
P(Y_{t+1} = 0 | Y_t = 0, X_t = 1) = 1 - q_{01}(\tau_t)
$$
Here:

$\tau_t$ represents the time since the last lightning strike, measured in hours.

$e^{-k\tau_t}$ is the exponential decay function:

$k \text{ is the decay rate (0.1 for } q_{11} \text{ and 0.05 for } q_{01}) $


When $X_t = 0$ (no thunderstorm), we set:
$$
P(Y_{t+1} = 0 | X_t = 0) = 1
$$
$$
P(Y_{t+1} = 1 | X_t = 0) = 0
$$
I then tried to define combined process as a 4-state Markov chain $(X_t, Y_t)$ with states $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(1,1)$, and $(0,1)$:
$$
S = \{(0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (0,1)\}
$$
$$(0,0) = \text{No thunderstorm, no lightning}$$
$$(1,0) = \text{Thunderstorm present, no lightning}$$
$$(1,1) = \text{Thunderstorm present, lightning occurring}$$
$$(0,1) = \text{No thunderstorm, lightning occurring}$$
$$
P = \begin{bmatrix}
p_{(0,0),(0,0)} & p_{(0,0),(1,0)} & p_{(0,0),(1,1)} & p_{(0,0),(0,1)} \\
p_{(1,0),(0,0)} & p_{(1,0),(1,0)} & p_{(1,0),(1,1)} & p_{(1,0),(0,1)} \\
p_{(1,1),(0,0)} & p_{(1,1),(1,0)} & p_{(1,1),(1,1)} & p_{(1,1),(0,1)} \\
p_{(0,1),(0,0)} & p_{(0,1),(1,0)} & p_{(0,1),(1,1)} & p_{(0,1),(0,1)}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
P = \begin{bmatrix}
0.9 & 0.1 \cdot (1-q_{01}(\tau_t)) & 0.1 \cdot q_{01}(\tau_t) & 0 \\
0.4 & 0.6 \cdot (1-q_{01}(\tau_t)) & 0.6 \cdot q_{01}(\tau_t) & 0 \\
0.4 & 0.6 \cdot (1-q_{11}(\tau_t)) & 0.6 \cdot q_{11}(\tau_t) & 0 \\
0.9 & 0.1 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Part 3: Justification:
I wanted to use the exponential decay function because of the following to ensure the Markov Chain mimics the following properties of thunderstorms:

Right after a lightning strike ($\tau_t = 0$), the probability of another strike is high if there was just a strike ($q_{11}(0) = 0.8$), but low if there wasn't ($q_{01}(0) = 0.1$).
As time passes without a strike (increasing $\tau_t$), both probabilities approach 0.5, representing a "reset" to a neutral state within the thunderstorm.

Conclusion: Can someone please tell me if the analysis I have presented looks logical?

While it's not exactly what you're describing here, you might be interested in looking into hidden Markov models

It seems that $\tau_t$ is itself a random variable. Are you also conditioning on that?

@ Asbjørn Holk: thanks for the suggestion!

@ Zack Fisher: Yes, Tau will be a random variable ...

As hinted at in the comments, your process will work in the framework of Markov chains only if you also include $\tau$ as part of it. That is, your process is $M_t=(X_t,Y_t,\tau_t)$ which takes values on the state space $S=\{0,1\}\times\{0,1\}\times\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$. This satisfies the Markov property, which informally states that knowing just the current state of the process gives you as much information about its future behaviour as knowing the current state and entire history of the process (which was not true for $(X_t,Y_t)$).
